# How to set stdcpp+17 in a property sheet for Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, c++17, propertysheet

I have a solution with a large number (120+) of projects.   I'd like to enable stdc++-17 in all of them without changing each individual project.   We are already using a property sheet.  I just can't figure out how to add the flag with the proper nesting.  I believe the proper syntax for the flag is as below, but not sure what it should be nested inside:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <LanguageStandard>stdcpp17</LanguageStandard>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This does not work.  Does anyone the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a compiler setting, which should go into a `ClCompile` section. To have it apply to all configurations, leave the section *not* qualified with any additional `Condition`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<!-- ... -->
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>
      <LanguageStandard>stdcpp17</LanguageStandard>
```